# Datastore object Key field

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Does the GAE datastore API (Go) support returning the key on an object by default?

Currently I'm solving this by updating an ignored `Key` field manually in code after writes and fetches like this:

```
type User struct {
  Key    *datastore.Key `datastore:"-"`
  Email  string
  ...
}
```

Do I have to do this or is there a way that makes that redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to maintain that field yourself. You can write a function using reflection which can perform that work on any struct, but there is no method in the appengine SDK to do what you want.